# create javafx reusable components

Tags: javafx

When I was creating some app using javafx, I found similar constructs appear multiple times in my fxml files:

```
<HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="5">
  <padding>
    <Insets bottom="5.4" left="6.5" right="6.5" top="5.4" />
  </padding>
  <children>
  ......
  </children>
</HBox>
```

The only differences are the children.  I want to have some way to avoid specifying the common attributes everywhere.  Is there a easy way to do that?

I know we can have custom components in javafx but that requires implementing a custom Controller class, which is over kill for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate fxml for commonly used components and then add them in another fxml using fx:include tag..